# Xreate two output xml files using one input xml.?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have an attribute in my input xml file with the value 'true'. For eg: true. So whenever I get this value as true, I need to call two xsl's to create two different outputs. Is that possible?

Until now, I have got the value as false and I didn't need to call more than one xsl file to process.

Comment: In XSLT 1.0, a single transformation will result in a single output (unless your processor supports multiple outputs as an extension). So the problem needs to be solved at the calling application level.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].